# Scale Variable of dataframe to another dataframe Variable

Tags: r, dataframe, scale

I have two dataframes as shown in the tables below.I need to scale the variable (wind_speed) of the second dataframe based on the wind speed of the first dataframe and I do not have any idea on how to implement this task.

How can I achieve that in R?

**DATAFRAME 1**

| WIND_SPEED | KWH |
| --- | --- |
| 4.2 | 2340 |
| 4.6 | 4245 |
| 5.2 | 2340 |
| 5.8 | 4245 |

**DATAFRAME 2**

| WIND_SPEED | KWH |
| --- | --- |
| 8.4 | 9870 |
| 6.8 | 7605 |
| 5.4 | 3645 |
| 4.4 | 1665 |

Comment: `(x - mean(y)) / std(y)` where `x` is each value of 2nd dataframe which we normalise based on the mean and standard deviation of the values in your first dataframe

Comment: @Sotos thank you! How can I ignore the Na values while performing this operation?

Comment: There is an argument `na.rm` which you should set to TRUE inside mean and std